# Adding touchscreen to laptop and need to use USB extension cable

Tags: windows-7, laptop, usb, drivers, multiple-monitors

I have a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit Dell/Alienware laptop and bought a Faytech 15" touchscreen to add to it, the laptop runs 3D marine charting software (thus the need for the Alienware model), the second screen is remote mounted about 13 feet away on the back deck of the boat. The Faytech monitor has HDMI for video, USB for the touch, and 12VDC power needs, the whole ball of wax works perfect when the USB is plugged directly to the laptop, but installing a 15' extension USB cable causes "unknown device".... I have tried passive and active USB extension cables to no avail. When the screen is plugged directly to the laptop it loads standard windows drivers for a mouse and works fine. With the extension is won't load any drivers, or seem to let me point to any drivers. Any help appreciated, word of caution; speak with simpleton terms or you'll be over my head quickly.... thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Hi Chris - the maximum cable length you can use unpowered is 4.5 to 5 meters. Above that length, the signal will repidly detoriate resulting in - as you've seen - unknown devices. It is possible to serialise usb cables but this approach would involve power boosters along the way - wheter this is feasible on the boat is a question i cannot answer.

Comment: I have tried passive and active(powered) USB cables, both 5 meters long same result.... no issue grabbing any DC voltage on the boat, but not sure if this is hardware or driver issue???

Comment: Bit more to add- the touchscreen works perfect on my desktop pc with the active extension cable it is Win 7 64 bit OS, but thus far have tried two laptops, both Win 7 64 bit, and both same results, unknown device....

Comment: Hi Chris - the fact that the extension cable work on a desktop is semi-good news ruling out possible hardware fault on the cable itself. As i don't know the specs of your desktop, i would suggest that you dload the Faytech aio driver package from http://www.faytech.com/services/driver-downloads/ and load the included USB driver for the unknown entry you receive when the extension cable is being used. One other thing to bear in mind, the USB connector in your desktop is likely able to bear a bigger load that laptops,

Comment: So what you can try is launch power options on the laptop and disable USB selective suspend under advanced power settings. [Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options\Edit Plan Settings]